# How do I create a directory inside container with JIB?

Tags: jib

I am trying to specify a mount point in a kubernetes deployment descriptor and for that I need there to be a directory

```
volumeMounts:
            - name: volume-mount
              mountPath: /dev/bus/usb/003/005
```

to correspond to:

```
volumes:
        - name: my-host-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /dev/bus/usb/003/005
```

How do I create this using jib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**: newer Jib versions have the [feature](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/1581) to allow specifying a copy destination directory when using `<extraDirectories>`. You no longer have to manually prepare the target directory structure beforehand.

---

Create an empty directory `<project root>/src/main/jib/dev/bus/usb/003/005` in your source repo.

#### Details

Jib allows adding arbitrary extra files and directories using the `<extraDirectories>` ([Maven](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image) / [Gradle](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#adding-arbitrary-files-to-the-image)) configuration. Files and (sub-)directories under `<extraDirectories>` will be recursively copied into the root directory of the image. By default, `<project root>/src/main/jib` is one such "extra directory", so you can simply create an empty directory with the structure you like.

You can also tune the permissions of files and directories using `<permissions>` if you want.